# Datagridview comboboxcell dissappears when clicking columnname

Tags: .net, powershell, winforms, datagridview

I have an issue that when I click any column name in my datagridview all comboboxes become normal textboxes and they don't turn back without restarting the script. I suspect that this might have something todo with ordering columns so I tried `$script:dataGridView2.AllowUserToOrderColumns = $False;` but that's not working properly.

Here's my code; I initially removed a lot of stuff I thought that was unnecessary but that didn't work so here's the whole script with a few parts edited:

```
Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
    [ValidateSet("Live", "Prelive", "Entwicklung_TG", "Entwicklung_ER")]
    [String]$Stage = "Prelive"
)

#region0 externe Komponenten
# SkriptVersion
[string]$Script:Version = "0.0.0.0" 

if($Stage -eq "Live"){
  $Toolspath = "\\X\Tools.ps1"
}
elseif($Stage -eq "Prelive"){
  $Toolspath = "\\Y\Tools.ps1"
}
elseif($Stage -eq "Entwicklung_TG"){
$Toolspath = "D:\Z\Tools.ps1"
}
elseif($Stage -eq "Entwicklung_ER"){
  $Toolspath = "\\A\Tools.ps1"
}

if (Test-Path $Toolspath) {
    . (Get-Item $Toolspath)
}
elseif(Test-Path ((Get-Item -Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path).DirectoryName + "\Tools.ps1")){
    . ((Get-Item -Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path).DirectoryName + "\Tools.ps1")    
}
else{
    Write-Host "Es konnte kein Tools-Skript eingebunden werden. Das Skript wird beendet."
    echo
    exit
}
#endregion0

#region1 Globale Variable
[string]$script:LogLauf='1'
[string]$script:Stage = $stage
[string]$script:Periode = $Periode

$script:GrundParam = get-Grundparameter -Stage $Stage -Periode $Periode -LoggingTabelle $LoggingTabelle

#Folgende Werte werden als Grundparameter zurückgeliefert
[string]$script:CS_Systempruefung = $script:GrundParam.CS_Systempruefung;
[string]$script:CS_Gradient = $script:GrundParam.CS_Gradient;
[string]$script:CS_KVnet = $script:GrundParam.CS_KVnet;
[string]$script:CS_Logging = $script:GrundParam.CS_Logging;
[string]$script:LoggingTabelle = $script:GrundParam.LoggingTabelle;
[string]$script:LogLaufId = $script:GrundParam.LogLaufId;
[string]$script:Fileserver = $script:GrundParam.Fileserver;
[string]$script:Auslieferungspfad = $script:GrundParam.Auslieferungspfad;
[string]$script:Einzelinstanz_gerade = $script:GrundParam.Einzelinstanz_gerade;
[string]$script:Einzelinstanz_ungerade = $script:GrundParam.Einzelinstanz_ungerade;
[string]$script:DWH_Sammelinstanz = $script:GrundParam.DWH_Sammelinstanz;
[string]$script:Sammelinstanz = $script:GrundParam.Sammelinstanz;
[string]$script:AkonInstanz = $script:GrundParam.AkonInstanz;
[string]$script:KVOnlineInstanz = $script:GrundParam.KVOnlineInstanz;

#Zusätzliche Parameter bei angabe einer Periode
[string]$script:Periode = $Periode;
[string]$script:CS_Periode = $script:GrundParam.CS_Periode;
[string]$script:CS_Workflow  = $script:GrundParam.CS_Workflow;
#[string]$script:CS_Intermediate = $script:GrundParam.CS_Intermediate;
[string]$script:PeriodenInstanz = $script:GrundParam.PeriodenInstanz;
[string]$script:Sammelinstanz_Periode = $script:GrundParam.Sammelinstanz_Periode;
#[string]$script:IntermediateInstanz = $script:GrundParam.IntermediateInstanz;
[string]$script:IntermediateDB = $script:GrundParam.IntermediateDB;
[string]$script:PeriodenId = $script:GrundParam.PeriodenId;
[string]$script:KVnetTyp = $script:GrundParam.KVnetTyp;
#endregion

#region2 Functions
    function DG-Filter {
        if ($script:txtFilterListe.SelectedIndex -ne 0 -and $script:txtFilter.Text -and $script:txtFilter.Text -ne 'Bitte Filter eingeben...'){
            $script:AWtable1.DefaultView.RowFilter = "$($script:txtFilterListe.SelectedItem) LIKE '%$($script:txtFilter.Text)%'"
            $info = "Test"
        }
        else{
            $script:AWtable1.DefaultView.RowFilter = ""
        }
        $script:dataGridView1.Refresh()
    }

    function Prefill-DGV2 {
        #LogId
        $Script:AWtable2.Rows[0].LogId = 0;

        #Team
        $Script:AWtable2.Rows[0].Team = 'IT-Anwendungsbetrieb';
    }

    function InsertEntry {
        PM_DB-TableWrite -Periode Live -SQL ("<Insert-Statement>") -ConnectionString $script:CS_Systempruefung -LogConnectionString $script:CS_Logging -LogTable $script:LoggingTabelle -TestName Anwendungstagebuch;
    }
#endregion

#region3.MainForm

    function GenerateForm {
        Add-Type -assembly System.Windows.Forms;

        #region.FormParameter
            $script:form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form;
            $script:form.Name = 'form1';
            $script:form.Text = 'Anwendungstagebuch';
            $script:form.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0;
            $script:form.Size = '1310, 787';
            $script:form.MinimumSize = '1310, 787';
            $script:form.StartPosition = 1;
            $script:form.BackColor = '#3D6387';
        #endregion

        #region.Datasources
            #region.Datasource1 - DGV1
                #SQL
                $script:AWtable1 = New-Object system.Data.DataTable 'AWTable';
                $script:AWtable1 = PM_DB-TableResult -Periode Live -SQL ("<Select-Statement>") -ConnectionString $script:CS_Systempruefung -LogConnectionString $script:CS_Logging -LogTable $script:LoggingTabelle -TestName Anwendungstagebuch;
            #endregion

            #region.Datasource2 - DGV2
                $script:AWtable2 = New-Object System.Data.DataTable;
                $script:AWAddColumnNames2 = $script:AWtable1.Columns.ColumnName | ForEach-Object {$AWnewcol2 = New-Object system.Data.DataColumn $_,([string]); $script:AWtable2.columns.add($AWnewcol2)};
                #Add empty rows
                $script:NewRow1 = $script:AWtable2.NewRow()
                $script:AWtable2.Rows.Add($script:NewRow1)
            #endregion

            #region.Datasource3 - DGV2Dropdown
                #AWAusgeführtVon
                $script:AWArray1 = @('Bitte auswählen','user1', 'user2', 'user3', 'user4', 'user5', 'user6')

                #AWStage
                $script:AWArray2 = @('Bitte auswählen','PreLive','Live')
            #endregion
        #endregion
    
        #region.txtFilterListe
            $script:txtFilterListe = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox;
            $script:txtFilterListe.Name = 'txtFilterListe';
            $script:txtFilterListe.Text = 'Bitte Spalte auswählen';
            $script:txtFilterListe.TabIndex = 0;
            $script:txtFilterListe.Size = '150, 21';
            $script:txtFilterListe.Location = '13, 21';
            $script:txtFilterListe.DropDownStyle = 2;
            $script:txtFilterListe.IntegralHeight = 1;

            #Dropdown mit Tabellenüberschriften befüllen
            #$script:FilterContent = $Script:AWtable1.Columns | select $_.ColumnName | ForEach-Object {[void] $script:txtFilterListe.Items.Add($_)};
            $script:txtFilterListeIndexes = @(1,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17)
            foreach($i in $script:txtFilterListeIndexes){
                $script:txtFilterListe.Items.Add($script:AWtable1.Columns[$i].ColumnName)
            }

            #DropdownPlaceholder
            $script:txtFilterListe.Items.Insert(0, "Bitte Spalte auswählen");
            $script:txtFilterListe.SelectedIndex = 0;
        #endregion

        #region.FilterTextfeld
            $script:txtFilter = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox;
            $script:txtFilter.Text = 'Bitte Filter eingeben...';
            $script:txtFilter.Name = 'txtFilter';
            $script:txtFilter.TabIndex = 1;
            $script:txtFilter.Size = '398, 20';
            $script:txtFilter.Location = '170, 22';
            $script:txtFilter.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0;
            $script:txtFilter.Enabled = 0;

            #Textfeld freigeben/sperren
            $script:txtFilterListe.add_selectedindexchanged({
                $script:txtFilter.Text = 'Bitte Filter eingeben...'
                if ($script:txtFilterListe.SelectedIndex -gt 0){
                    $script:txtFilter.Enabled = 1;
                }
                else {
                    $script:txtFilter.Enabled = 0;
                    &DG-Filter
                }
            })

            #FilterPlaceholder
            $script:txtFilter.Add_GotFocus({
                if ($script:txtFilter.Text -eq 'Bitte Filter eingeben...'){
                    $txtFilter.Text = '';
                }
            })
            $script:txtFilter.Add_LostFocus({
                if ($script:txtFilter.Text -eq '') {
                    $txtFilter.Text = 'Bitte Filter eingeben...';
                }
            })
            $script:txtFilter.Add_TextChanged({
                &DG-Filter
            })
        #endregion

        #region.Groupbox1
            $script:groupbox1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox;
            $script:groupbox1.FlatStyle = 0;
            $script:groupbox1.Text = 'Filter';
            $script:groupbox1.ForeColor = '#ffffff';
            $script:groupbox1.AutoSize = $true;
            $script:groupbox1.Size = '585, 50';
            $script:groupbox1.Location = '13, 13';
            $script:groupbox1.Controls.Add($script:txtFilterListe);
            $script:groupbox1.Controls.Add($script:txtFilter);
        #endregion

        #region.Groupbox2
            #DataGridView1 - Anwendungstagebuch
            $script:dataGridView1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView;
            $script:dataGridView1.Name = 'dataGridView1';
            $script:dataGridView1.Size = '1235, 441';
            $script:dataGridView1.Anchor = (4, 8, 1);
            $script:dataGridView1.Location = '13, 21';
            $script:dataGridView1.RowTemplate.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = '#000096';
            $script:dataGridView1.TabIndex = 3;
            $script:dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = 2;
            $script:dataGridView1.ReadOnly = $True;
            $script:dataGridView1.RowHeadersVisible = $True;
            $script:dataGridView1.RowHeadersWidth = 24;
            $script:dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = $False;
            $script:dataGridView1.AllowUserToDeleteRows = $False;
            $script:dataGridView1.AllowUserToOrderColumns = $True;
            $script:dataGridView1.DataSource = $script:AWtable1;
            $script:dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = $false;
            $script:dataGridView1.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0;

            #region.DGV1Add Columns and assign Values
                #Periode
                $script:dataGridView1.Columns.Add("Periode", "Periode")
                $script:dataGridView1.Columns[0].DataPropertyName = "Periode";
                #Durchfuehrungsdatum
                $script:dataGridView1.Columns.Add("Durchfuehrungsdatum", "Durchfuehrungsdatum")
                $script:dataGridView1.Columns[1].DataPropertyName = "Durchfuehrungsdatum";
                #Aenderung
                $script:dataGridView1.Columns.Add("Aenderung", "Aenderung")
                $script:dataGridView1.Columns[2].DataPropertyName = "Aenderung";
                #DurchgeführtVon
                $script:dataGridView1.Columns.Add("DurchgeführtVon", "DurchgeführtVon")
                $script:dataGridView1.Columns[3].DataPropertyName = "DurchgeführtVon";
                #Team
                $script:dataGridView1.Columns.Add("Team", "Team")
                $script:dataGridView1.Columns[4].DataPropertyName = "Team";
                #Service
                $script:dataGridView1.Columns.Add("Service", "Service")
                $script:dataGridView1.Columns[5].DataPropertyName = "Service";
                #Komponente
                $script:dataGridView1.Columns.Add("Komponente", "Komponente")
                $script:dataGridView1.Columns[6].DataPropertyName = "Komponente";
                #Stage
                $script:dataGridView1.Columns.Add("Stage", "Stage")
                $script:dataGridView1.Columns[7].DataPropertyName = "Stage";
                #Aufgabentyp
                $script:dataGridView1.Columns.Add("Aufgabentyp", "Aufgabentyp")
                $script:dataGridView1.Columns[8].DataPropertyName = "Aufgabentyp";
                #Server
                $script:dataGridView1.Columns.Add("Server", "Server")
                $script:dataGridView1.Columns[9].DataPropertyName = "Server";
                #ServerIPAdresse
                $script:dataGridView1.Columns.Add("ServerIPAdresse", "ServerIPAdresse")
                $script:dataGridView1.Columns[10].DataPropertyName = "ServerIPAdresse";
                #sonstigeBemerkung
                $script:dataGridView1.Columns.Add("sonstigeBemerkung", "sonstigeBemerkung")
                $script:dataGridView1.Columns[11].DataPropertyName = "sonstigeBemerkung";
                #IncidentNr
                $script:dataGridView1.Columns.Add("IncidentNr", "IncidentNr")
                $script:dataGridView1.Columns[12].DataPropertyName = "IncidentNr";
                #ChangeNr
                $script:dataGridView1.Columns.Add("ChangeNr", "ChangeNr")
                $script:dataGridView1.Columns[13].DataPropertyName = "ChangeNr";
                #ServiceRequestNr
                $script:dataGridView1.Columns.Add("ServiceRequestNr", "ServiceRequestNr")
                $script:dataGridView1.Columns[14].DataPropertyName = "ServiceRequestNr";
                #ReleaseNr
                $script:dataGridView1.Columns.Add("ReleaseNr", "ReleaseNr")
                $script:dataGridView1.Columns[15].DataPropertyName = "ReleaseNr";
            #endregion

            #btnSave Parameters
            $script:btnSave = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button;
            $script:btnSave.Name = 'btnSave';
            $script:btnSave.Size = '100, 21';
            $script:btnSave.Location = '13, 475';
            $script:btnSave.Text = 'Save';
            $script:btnSave.UseVisualStyleBackColor = 1;
            $script:btnSave.ForeColor = '#000000';
            $script:btnSave.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0;
            $script:btnSave.Enabled = 0;

            #btnEdit Parameters
            $script:btnEdit = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button;
            $script:btnEdit.Name = 'btnEdit';
            $script:btnEdit.Size = '100, 21';
            $script:btnEdit.Location = '126, 475';
            $script:btnEdit.Text = 'Edit';
            $script:btnEdit.UseVisualStyleBackColor = 1;
            $script:btnEdit.ForeColor = '#000000';
            $script:btnEdit.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0;

            #btnDelete Parameters
            $script:btnDelete = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button;
            $script:btnDelete.Name = 'btnDelete';
            $script:btnDelete.Size = '100, 21';
            $script:btnDelete.Location = '239, 475';
            $script:btnDelete.Text = 'Delete';
            $script:btnDelete.UseVisualStyleBackColor = 1;
            $script:btnDelete.ForeColor = '#000000';
            $script:btnDelete.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0;

            #Groupbox Parameters
            $script:groupbox2 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox;
            $script:groupbox2.FlatStyle = 0;
            $script:groupbox2.Size = '1265, 510';
            $script:groupbox2.Location = '13, 85';
            $script:groupbox2.Anchor = (4, 8, 1);
            $script:groupbox2.Text = 'Anwendungstagebuch';
            $script:groupbox2.ForeColor = '#ffffff';
            $script:groupbox2.AutoSize = $true;
            $script:groupbox2.Controls.Add($script:dataGridView1);
            $script:groupbox2.Controls.Add($script:btnEdit);
            $script:groupbox2.Controls.Add($script:btnDelete);
            $script:groupbox2.Controls.Add($script:btnSave);
        #endregion

        #region.Groupbox3
            #DataGridView2 - Eintrag hinzufügen
            $script:dataGridView2 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView;
            $script:dataGridView2.Name = 'dataGridView2';
            $script:dataGridView2.Size = '1235, 44';
            $script:dataGridView2.Location = '13, 21';
            $script:dataGridView2.Anchor = (4, 8, 1);
            $script:dataGridView2.TabIndex = 4;
            $script:dataGridView2.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = 2;
            $script:dataGridView2.ReadOnly = $False;
            $script:dataGridView2.RowHeadersVisible = $True;
            $script:dataGridView2.RowHeadersWidth = 24;
            $script:dataGridView2.AllowUserToAddRows = $False;
            $script:dataGridView2.AllowUserToDeleteRows = $False;
            $script:dataGridView2.AllowUserToOrderColumns = $False;
            $script:dataGridView2.DataSource = $script:AWtable2;
            $script:dataGridView2.AutoGenerateColumns = $false;
            $script:dataGridView2.EditMode = 0;
            $script:dataGridView2.ScrollBars = 0;

            #region.DGV2Add Columns and assign Values
                #Periode
                $script:dataGridView2.Columns.Add("Periode", "Periode")
                $script:dataGridView2.Columns[0].DataPropertyName = "Periode";
                #Aenderung
                $script:dataGridView2.Columns.Add("Aenderung", "Aenderung")
                $script:dataGridView2.Columns[1].DataPropertyName = "Aenderung";
                #DurchgeführtVon
                $script:dataGridView2.Columns.Add("DurchgeführtVon", "DurchgeführtVon")
                $script:dataGridView2.Columns[2].DataPropertyName = "DurchgeführtVon";
                #Team
                $script:dataGridView2.Columns.Add("Team", "Team")
                $script:dataGridView2.Columns[3].DataPropertyName = "Team";
                #Service
                $script:dataGridView2.Columns.Add("Service", "Service")
                $script:dataGridView2.Columns[4].DataPropertyName = "Service";
                #Komponente
                $script:dataGridView2.Columns.Add("Komponente", "Komponente")
                $script:dataGridView2.Columns[5].DataPropertyName = "Komponente";
                #Stage
                $script:dataGridView2.Columns.Add("Stage", "Stage")
                $script:dataGridView2.Columns[6].DataPropertyName = "Stage";
                #Aufgabentyp
                $script:dataGridView2.Columns.Add("Aufgabentyp", "Aufgabentyp")
                $script:dataGridView2.Columns[7].DataPropertyName = "Aufgabentyp";
                #Server
                $script:dataGridView2.Columns.Add("Server", "Server")
                $script:dataGridView2.Columns[8].DataPropertyName = "Server";
                #ServerIPAdresse
                $script:dataGridView2.Columns.Add("ServerIPAdresse", "ServerIPAdresse")
                $script:dataGridView2.Columns[9].DataPropertyName = "ServerIPAdresse";
                #sonstigeBemerkung
                $script:dataGridView2.Columns.Add("sonstigeBemerkung", "sonstigeBemerkung")
                $script:dataGridView2.Columns[10].DataPropertyName = "sonstigeBemerkung";
                #IncidentNr
                $script:dataGridView2.Columns.Add("IncidentNr", "IncidentNr")
                $script:dataGridView2.Columns[11].DataPropertyName = "IncidentNr";
                #ChangeNr
                $script:dataGridView2.Columns.Add("ChangeNr", "ChangeNr")
                $script:dataGridView2.Columns[12].DataPropertyName = "ChangeNr";
                #ServiceRequestNr
                $script:dataGridView2.Columns.Add("ServiceRequestNr", "ServiceRequestNr")
                $script:dataGridView2.Columns[13].DataPropertyName = "ServiceRequestNr";
                #ReleaseNr
                $script:dataGridView2.Columns.Add("ReleaseNr", "ReleaseNr")
                $script:dataGridView2.Columns[14].DataPropertyName = "ReleaseNr";
            #endregion

            #DGV befüllen
            &Prefill-DGV2

            #DGV2 ReadOnly Columns
            $script:dataGridView2.Columns[3].ReadOnly = $true;

            #btnAdd Parameters
            $script:btnAdd = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button;
            $script:btnAdd.Name = 'btnAdd';
            $script:btnAdd.Size = '100, 21';
            $script:btnAdd.Location = '13, 80';
            $script:btnAdd.Text = 'Add';
            $script:btnAdd.UseVisualStyleBackColor = 1;
            $script:btnAdd.ForeColor = '#000000';
            $script:btnAdd.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0;
            $script:btnAdd.Enabled = 0;

            #btnAdd EventHandler
            $script:btnAdd.Add_Click({
                $script:currentAddTime = Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff"
                #&InsertEntry
            })

            #Groupbox Parameters
            $script:groupbox3 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox;
            $script:groupbox3.Size = '1265, 113';
            $script:groupbox3.Location = '13, 615';
            $script:groupbox3.Anchor = (4, 8, 1);
            $script:groupbox3.FlatStyle = 0;
            $script:groupbox3.Text = 'Neuer Eintrag';
            $script:groupbox3.ForeColor = '#ffffff';
            $script:groupbox3.AutoSize = $true;
            $script:groupbox3.Controls.Add($script:dataGridView2);
            $script:groupbox3.Controls.Add($script:btnAdd);
        #endregion

        #region.dataGridView afterLoad settings
            $script:form.add_Load({
            
                #region.Configure Columnwidth 
                    # 1 = Not adjusted
                    # 2 = Adjusted to Columnname
                    # 4 = Adjusted to Value without Columnname
                    # 6 = Adjusted to Value and Columnname
                    # 8 = Adjusted to all at start visible Columns
                    # 16 = All Columns get adjusted to tablewidth

                    #DGV1 Autosizemode
                    $script:dataGridView1.Columns[0].AutoSizeMode = 4;      # Periode
                    $script:dataGridView1.Columns[1].AutoSizeMode = 4;      # Durchfuehrungsdatum
                    $script:dataGridView1.Columns[2].AutoSizeMode = 2;      # Aenderung
                    $script:dataGridView1.Columns[3].AutoSizeMode = 4;      # DurchgeführtVon
                    $script:dataGridView1.Columns[4].AutoSizeMode = 2;      # Team
                    $script:dataGridView1.Columns[5].AutoSizeMode = 4;      # Service
                    $script:dataGridView1.Columns[6].AutoSizeMode = 4;      # Komponente
                    $script:dataGridView1.Columns[7].AutoSizeMode = 4;      # Stage
                    $script:dataGridView1.Columns[8].AutoSizeMode = 4;      # Aufgabentyp
                    $script:dataGridView1.Columns[9].AutoSizeMode = 4;      # Server
                    $script:dataGridView1.Columns[10].AutoSizeMode = 4;     # ServerIPAdresse
                    $script:dataGridView1.Columns[11].AutoSizeMode = 2;     # sonstigeBemerkung
                    $script:dataGridView1.Columns[12].AutoSizeMode = 4;     # IncidentNr
                    $script:dataGridView1.Columns[13].AutoSizeMode = 4;     # ChagenNr
                    $script:dataGridView1.Columns[14].AutoSizeMode = 4;     # ServiceRequestNr
                    $script:dataGridView1.Columns[15].AutoSizeMode = 16;    # ReleaseNr

                    #DGV2 Column Width
                    $script:dataGridView2.Columns[0].Width = $script:dataGridView1.Columns[0].Width     # Periode
                    $script:dataGridView2.Columns[1].Width = $script:dataGridView1.Columns[2].Width     # Aenderung
                    $script:dataGridView2.Columns[2].Width = $script:dataGridView1.Columns[3].Width     # DurchgeführtVon
                    $script:dataGridView2.Columns[4].Width = $script:dataGridView1.Columns[5].Width     # Service
                    $script:dataGridView2.Columns[5].Width = $script:dataGridView1.Columns[6].Width     # Komponente
                    $script:dataGridView2.Columns[7].Width = $script:dataGridView1.Columns[8].Width     # Aufgabentyp
                    $script:dataGridView2.Columns[8].Width = $script:dataGridView1.Columns[9].Width     # Server

                    #DGV2 AutosizeMode
                    $script:dataGridView2.Columns[3].AutoSizeMode = 4;      # Team
                    $script:dataGridView2.Columns[6].AutoSizeMode = 6;      # Stage
                    $script:dataGridView2.Columns[9].AutoSizeMode = 4;      # ServerIPAdresse
                    $script:dataGridView2.Columns[10].AutoSizeMode = 2;     # sonstigeBemerkung
                    $script:dataGridView2.Columns[11].AutoSizeMode = 4;     # IncidentNr
                    $script:dataGridView2.Columns[12].AutoSizeMode = 4;     # ChangeNr
                    $script:dataGridView2.Columns[13].AutoSizeMode = 4;     # ServiceRequestNr
                    $script:dataGridView2.Columns[14].AutoSizeMode = 16;    # ReleaseNr

                    #Allow Resizing
                    for($i=0; $i -le $script:dataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1; $i=$i+1){
                        #Spaltenbreite speichern
                        $script:colw1 = $script:dataGridView1.Columns[$i].Width;
                        $script:dataGridView1.Columns[$i].AutoSizeMode = 1;
                        $script:dataGridView1.Columns[$i].Width = $script:colw1;
                        
                        if($i -le 14){
                            $script:colw2 = $script:dataGridView2.Columns[$i].Width;
                            $script:dataGridView2.Columns[$i].AutoSizeMode = 1;
                            $script:dataGridView2.Columns[$i].Width = $script:colw2;
                        }
                    }
                #endregion

                #DGV2 Forecolor
                $script:dataGridView2.ForeColor = '#000096';

                #region.DGV2 Dropdown Selection
                    #DurchgeführtVon
                    $script:cbDurchgef = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewComboBoxCell;
                    $script:cbDurchgef.Style.ForeColor = '#000000';
                    $script:cbDurchgef.DisplayStyle = 1;
                    $script:cbDurchgef.DataSource = $script:AWArray1;
                    #Stage
                    $script:cbStage = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewComboBoxCell;
                    $script:cbStage.Style.ForeColor = '#000000';
                    $script:cbStage.DisplayStyle = 1;
                    $script:cbStage.DataSource = $script:AWArray2;

                    #Assign ComboboxCell to UserCell
                    $script:dataGridView2.Rows[0].Cells[2] = $script:cbDurchgef;
                    $script:dataGridView2.Rows[0].Cells[6] = $script:cbStage;
                
                    #Change Dropdown Index
                    $script:dataGridView2.Rows[0].Cells[2].Value = "Bitte auswählen";
                    $script:dataGridView2.Rows[0].Cells[6].Value = "Bitte auswählen";
                #endregion
            })
        #endregion

        #region.AddControls
            $script:form.Controls.Add($groupbox1);
            $script:form.Controls.Add($groupbox2);
            $script:form.Controls.Add($groupbox3);
        #endregion


        #Form anzeigen
        [void]$form.ShowDialog();
    }

GenerateForm

#endregion
```

Does anyone know what could cause this/how I could fix this issue?

Comment: I just noticed that this cutdown version doesn't have this issue. Seems like it's in the part I removed then..

Comment: Why are you trying to set the Cells of a Row with ComboBoxCells created on the fly, instead of generating DataGridViewComboBoxColumns, so you can set their `DataSource` and `DisplayStyle` properties correctly? -- `dataGridView1` is undefined here

Comment: So instead of creating them right at the end (`$script:cbDurchgef` and `$script:cbStage`) I can create a ComboBoxColumn where I create all the other Columns? I've added the rest of my script, maybe that helps a bit although the data comes from a SQL-Statement so `dataGridView1` might not even help alot

Comment: Not exactly *I can create*, that's what you should do. The `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` exposes the DataSource property, which is then used to set the DataSource of the EditingControl, which is of course a ComboBox -- As mentioned, it also exposes the `DisplayStyle` Property

Comment: Alright, I'll try that but it seems that the original issue was somewhere else because it went away after I removed some parts that weren't needed. Not exactly sure what it was tho